# Emacs GNUS Fullscreen Article, Args out of range: 0

Tags: debugging, gnus

I'm trying to get GNUS to show article fullscreen after select on summary screen. I found out about `gnus-buffer-configuration` variable where is configuration of how screen should by displayed. I also found `gnus-add-configuration` function to modify. I tried to set article settings to:

```
(article
  (vertical 1.0
    (article 1.0 point)))
```

But when I try to open article I get `gnus-summary-show-thread: Args out of range: 0` and empty buffer is open in fullscreen.
I also tried without point:

```
(article
  (vertical 1.0
    (article 1.0)))
```

since I got same error when I tried to reset to default and I forgot to delete points from behind the article:

```
(gnus-add-configuration
 '(article
   (vertical 1.0
             (summary 0.25 point)
             (article 1.0 point))))
```

I also tried to get `(summary 0)` but that was some other error and I thing it also does not make much sense.

Anybody tried similar thing? How to setup GNUS to open article fullscreen?

EDIT: I tried to debug gnus a little bit and I find out that responsible function for shoving thread is `gnus-summary-show-thread`, but can't understand what exactly it is doing, from mi point of view I see only some tinkering with cursor position and something called overlays:

```
(defun gnus-summary-show-thread ()
  "Show thread subtrees.
Returns nil if no thread was there to be shown."
  (interactive nil gnus-summary-mode)
  (let* ((orig (point))
     (end (point-at-eol))
         (end (or (gnus-summary--inv end) (gnus-summary--inv (1- end))))
     ;; Leave point at bol
     (beg (progn (beginning-of-line) (if (bobp) (point) (1- (point)))))
     (eoi (and end (next-single-char-property-change end 'invisible))))
    (when eoi
      (remove-overlays beg eoi 'invisible 'gnus-sum)
      (goto-char orig)
      (gnus-summary-position-point)
      eoi)))
```

Comment: You seem to have misspelled `article` in a couple of places above. Make sure that it is *not* misspelled in the actual settings (and fix the question if so).

Comment: Thank you, I tried also with fixed names without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I end up copying body of `gnus-summary-scroll-up` under name `gnus-summary-scroll-up-same-window` and deleting layouting:

```
(defun gnus-summary-scroll-up-same-window (lines)
  "Own implementation of scroll up to show article in same window"
  (interactive "p" gnus-summary-mode)
  (gnus-configure-windows 'article)
  (gnus-summary-select-article nil nil 'pseudo))
```